# Which directory should I be in when installing ATP packages?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm planning to install a package through APT.

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

From which directory should I run the command?

I'm asking because I need to know if this will install everything to my current directory or will APT place the files in various different directories upon installation.

Comment: Where you are in Linux there you are in Linux - at home: command pwd shows you, where you are currently and cd (without parameters) brings you back at home in case you ran to far away into different directory.   :o)

Comment: I know which directory I'm in. I'm not sure I understand your comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter from which directory you call ´apt-get`. The files will always places in fixed directories specified by the specified and the APT configuration.

After you installed a package you can see where its files are installed by using

```
dpkg -L package_name
```

for example

```
dpkg -L gimp
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this Florian. May I ask if the same applies to the source code of programs I've manually download and installed? Would the source code and compiled code get stored in the current directory in this case?

Comment: For manually compiled programs it depends on the program. Usually `make install` or whatever they have for installing will install to a fixed directory, often somewhere in `/opt/` or `/usr/local/` by default. The documentation should tell you what the default is and how to change it.